# fall try to change picturebox image c#

Tags: c#

```
1. System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(@"C:\images\", newFileName));
```

1 compile answer:

> the process cannot access the file --- because it is being used by another process.

This file was using in `pictureBox` and I  want to change `pictureBox` image and exchange the file to new one.

I found answers to use `using` like this:

```
using (pictureMain.Image = new Bitmap(newFileName))
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

but it doesn't work because i need the picture to be visible all time..
Any solutions and i will be happy. Thanks

Comment: When posting a question, please check a) formatting, b) the language tags

Comment: Does the picture load once?

Comment: You need to make sure the bitmap is no longer referenced. This is a lot harder than it seems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is once the picture is loaded into the `PictureBox` it retains a *Handle* to the file. Hence why you cant copy it

To release the *File Handle*, you will need to [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) it.

```
// before copying the file make sure the file handle is released
// by calling dispose
if(PictureBox1.Image != null)
{
     PictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
     PictureBox1.Image = null;
} 

...

// It should be safe to copy the file now, as the handle should be released
File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(@"C:\images\",newFileName));
```

However, if you want to keep the image alive (Visually displayed) while trying to copy (which is what i think you are trying to do), you will essentially have to load the image, then clone it some how, then release the handle.

So i believe the following pattern should work for you when loading your image

```
// before loading any new image lets release any previously displayed imaged
if(PictureBox1.Image != null)
{
     PictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
     PictureBox1.Image = null;
} 

// this loads the image, copies it, then closes the handle
using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap("image_file_path"))
{
    PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bmpTemp);
}

...

// It should be safe to copy the file now, as the handle should be released
File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(@"C:\images\",     newFileName));
```

> **Final note**: After you have finished with the image, make sure you
>   dispose it. I.e if you create it, it needs to be disposed.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to load image, clone it and then release as follow.

```
using (Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(fileName))
    pictureMain.Image = new Bitmap(temp);
```

by this way file handle released and you can work with image that loaded into memory.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(@"C:\images\", newFileName));
```